# Override XmlTextWriter - Serializar Class para XML absolutamente todos os atributos

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Tenho minha classe:

```
    public class Pessoa 
    {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}
    }
```

Estou tentando serializar para XML essa minha classe.

```
public static string CreateXML(object o)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerialize = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter tw = new FullEndingXmlTextWritter(sw);

        xmlSerialize.Serialize(tw, o);
        return sw.ToString();
    }
```

Para isso, sobreescrevi o método `WriteEndElement` da classe `FullEndingXmlTextWritter` que herda de `XmlTextWriter`, com a intenção de gerar todas as tags

Segue:

```
public class FullEndingXmlTextWritter : XmlTextWriter
{
    public FullEndingXmlTextWritter(TextWriter w)
        : base(w)
    {
    }
    public FullEndingXmlTextWritter(System.IO.Stream w, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
        : base(w, encoding)
    {
    }
    public FullEndingXmlTextWritter(string fileName, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
        : base(fileName, encoding)
    {
    }
    public override void WriteEndElement()
    {
        base.WriteFullEndElement();
    }
}
```

Porém ao informar só o Id, por exemplo, ele não gera a tag `<nome>` também, que é o que eu quero, apenas Id

Quero que gere todas as tags de acordo com as propriedades da minha classe e não importando se as mesmas são vázias ou nullas.

Comment: tens noção de que estás a mudar o significado da seriação. Estás a transformar `null` em `""`-

Answer (score 1):

Experimente forçar um contrato de dados na sua classe, explicitando que a coluna pode ser nula:

```
[DataContract]
public class Pessoa 
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public string Nome {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo

Comment: @Rod Atualizei a resposta, agora prevendo que strings podem ser nulas.

Comment: Ao usar `IsNullable = True`, ele fica assim: `<Nome xsi:nil="true"> </Nome>` E eu gostaria que ficasse assim: `<Nome></Nome>` , Por isso tentei sobreescrever aquele método, caso contrário, nem iria precisar, bastava usar IsNullable mesmo

Comment: @Rod, tens noção de que estás a mudar o significado da seriação. Estás a transformar `null` em `""`-

Comment: Mas se é isso mesmo que queres, talvez possas intersetar a escrita do atributo `xsi:nil="true"` sobrepondo o método `WriteAttributeString`.

Answer (score 1):

Tendo em mente o alerta de @CiganoMorrisonMendez (que `<Nome xsi:nil="true"><Nome>` é diferente de `<Nome></Nome>`), se é realmente isso que você quer (assumir que a string nula é equivalente à string vazia), então você pode alterar a definição da sua classe `Pessoa` pra que essa equivalência seja explícita, usando a implementação da propriedade `Nome` para que ela sempre retorne um valor não-nulo, como mostrado no código abaixo.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Pessoa p = new Pessoa { Id = 123 };
        Console.WriteLine(CreateXML(p));
    }

    public static string CreateXML(object o)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerialize = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter tw = new FullEndingXmlTextWritter(sw);

        xmlSerialize.Serialize(tw, o);
        return sw.ToString();
    }

    public class FullEndingXmlTextWritter : XmlTextWriter
    {
        public FullEndingXmlTextWritter(TextWriter w)
            : base(w)
        {
        }

        public override void WriteEndElement()
        {
            base.WriteFullEndElement();
        }
    }
}

public class Pessoa
{
    private string nome;

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome
    {
        get { return nome ?? ""; }
        set { this.nome = value; }
    }
}
```